# Data.SE dumps are monthly... but when?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

I've been playing with our [awesome data site](https://data.stackexchange.com/) and wondering how frequently it's updated, and of course the FAQ says:

> **How frequently is Stack Exchange Data Explorer updated?**
>
> Data is updated monthly.

Great. When's that? Tomorrow? The 19th? First of each month? Whenever the manual process takes place? After second breakfast?

I don't need to know down to the second, but something with more resolution than 1/12th of a year would be awesome, or even something that tells me which dump I'm looking at.

Comment: I don't think "Data is updated monthly ***whenever the manual process takes place***" adds much info to the FAQ answer.... ;).

Comment: I'm sure there's a (good) duplicate out there, but it's updated via a manually-initiated process powered by [waffles](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/17174/waffles). It also doesn't directly correlate to the data dump; the last update for a given site is listed on the front page.

Comment: Hmmm I'm sure there was a blog post saying that SEDE data are now updated every couple of months... Can't find it though.

Comment: @Tim Stone: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:17174+%5Bdata-explorer%5D

Comment: @YannisRizos The data dump is now only released on a [quarterly schedule](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/creative-commons-data-dump-sep-11/).

Comment: @Tim I might have confused the post on the data dump with the SEDE update... For most sites SEDE data were last updated on Feb 2, if they don't get updated in the next couple of days, I'll start searching for that blog post.

Answer (score 8):

Data dumps are still a (mostly) manual process.  We run them once [every 3 months](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/creative-commons-data-dump-jan-11/), and get an upload to clearbits.

Originally we published everything monthly, and then bi-monthly.  The scale of getting these backups together (in particular, the final upload step is *really* finicky) has pushed the schedule back.

We do, however, try and keep data.se to a weekly schedule.  It was a monthly manual process however, and was basically "whenever waffles has the time this month". Nowadays there is simple batch job that runs every Sunday at 03:00 UTC.

Comment: Hmm... I wonder if my Data Server could be adapted to spit out XML files similar to the data dumps. If it was able to do that, then we could generate up-to-date data dumps on command. Any Qt developers around that would be interested? :)

Comment: Now that waffles has moved on, is this still manual?